# OpenGL - Water waves (with noise)

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex, vertex-shader

I am currently in the process of making water waves, so basically I am starting from the beginning. I have created a mesh which is basically a flat square and have animated it in the vertex shader (below is the code which achieves that)

```
vtx.y = (sin(2.0 * vtx.x + a_time/1000.0 ) * cos(1.5 * vtx.y + a_time/1000.0) * 0.2);
```

Basically just moving the y position based on a sin and cos function, the results of this can be observed [here](https://youtu.be/S5ZWJ98AKDQ)!

I then tried adding some Perlin noise (as per the Perlin noise functions by Ian McEwan, available here github.com/ashima/webgl-noise) as follows

```
vtx.y = vtx.y + 0.1*cnoise((a_time/5000.0)*a_vertex.yz);
```

the results of this can be observed [here](https://youtu.be/KLuZAkEI05I)!

As you can plainly observe there is no real "random" effect that I was looking for (simulate some basic random roughness of an ocean).

I was wondering how it would be possible for me to achieve this (also any suggestions on how to improve either of the functions that change y would also be appreciated).

Comment: i used fourier transforms once to do waves, as described here: http://www.keithlantz.net/2011/10/ocean-simulation-part-one-using-the-discrete-fourier-transform/

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution, is to use texture, that contain needed noise. If the displacement is kept in the texture, then it is possible to apply the displacement in the vertex shader, so there would be no need to modify vertex buffer. To make the waves moving, your may add some animated offset.
There are plenty of ways to fake, as you say, the "random" effect. You make take two samples from texture, using differently changing offsets and then simply add two displacements.

For example, see the following vertex shader:

```
uniform sampler2D u_heightMap;
uniform float u_time;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix 
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix 
attribute vec3 position;

void main()
{
    vec3 pos = position;
    vec2 offset1 = vec2(0.8, 0.4) * u_time * 0.1;
    vec2 offset2 = vec2(0.6, 1.1) * u_time * 0.1;
    float hight1 = texture2D(u_heightMap, uv + offset1).r * 0.02;
    float hight2 = texture2D(u_heightMap, uv + offset2).r * 0.02;
    pos.z += hight1 + hight2; 
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( pos, 1.0 );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
```

I've made a simple example using threejs:

```js
var container;
   var camera, scene, renderer;
   var mesh;
   var uniforms;

   var clock = new THREE.Clock();

   init();
   animate();

   function init() {
     container = document.getElementById('container');

     camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
     camera.position.z = 0.6;
     camera.position.y = 0.2;
     camera.rotation.x = -0.45;

     scene = new THREE.Scene();

     var boxGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.75, 0.75, 100, 100);
     
     var heightMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("data:image/png;base64,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");
     
     heightMap.wrapT = heightMap.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

     uniforms = {u_time: {type: "f", value: 0.0 }, u_heightMap: {type: "t",value:heightMap} };

     var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
       uniforms: uniforms,
       side: THREE.DoubleSide, 
       wireframe: true,
       vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
       fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment_shader').textContent
     });

     mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, material);
     mesh.rotation.x = 3.14 / 2.0;
     scene.add(mesh);

     renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
     renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1 );
     container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

     onWindowResize();

     window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

   }

   function onWindowResize(event) {
     camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
     camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
     renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   }

   function animate() {
     requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     render();
   }

   function render() {
     var delta = clock.getDelta();
     uniforms.u_time.value += delta;
     mesh.rotation.z += delta * 0.5;
     renderer.render(scene, camera);
   }
```

```css
body { margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>

<script id="fragment_shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    void main( void ) 
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0.0), 1.0);    
    }
</script>

<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
 uniform lowp sampler2D u_heightMap;
 uniform float u_time;
                
    void main()
    {
        vec3 pos = position;
        vec2 offset1 = vec2(1.0, 0.5) * u_time * 0.1;
        vec2 offset2 = vec2(0.5, 1.0) * u_time * 0.1;
        float hight1 = texture2D(u_heightMap, uv + offset1).r * 0.02;
        float hight2 = texture2D(u_heightMap, uv + offset2).r * 0.02;
        pos.z += hight1 + hight2; 
  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( pos, 1.0 );
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    }
</script>
```

Using better displacement texture, or even using two different textures for two offsets you may achieve better results.